# Meaning of "Voice going crazy on this hook like a whirlwind?"

Tags: american-english

What is the meaning of this phrase:

> Voice going crazy on this hook like a whirlwind?

It's from the song called [*Boyfriend*](https://genius.com/Madilyn-bailey-boyfriend-lyrics).

In context, the lyrics say:

> Girlfriend, girlfriend, I could be you girlfriend
>   I could be your girlfriend until until the world ends
>   Make you dance do a spin and a twirl and
>   Voice going crazy on this hook like a whirlwind

Answer (score 0):

The only word with a "difficult" meaning is "hook", which means "a catchy melody in a popular song" (it is the part of the song that catches your attention, hence "hook")

Apart from that the meaning is "(the) voice (is) going crazy (during) this (catchy melody) like a (tornado)".

I don't know why the why the song writer chose to use the metaphor of whirlwind, but it is probably something to do with dancing.

There is no special meaning to the other words, and we can't do lyric interpretation.

Comment: I think much of the reason for selecting "whirlwind" as a metaphor is that it's close enough phonetically to pass as a near-rhyme with "twirl and" in the previous line.

Comment: Yes. it sounds more like a rhyme if I do an American accent.